# About Join in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have four table given below

first one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ebqh.png)

2nd is **retration** table

filds st_name, Adhar no, address, exam_level

trans temp table
hire student adhar no. is there and amount detail for payment
fields are
`id`, `student_id`, `reference_no`, `sub_merchant_id`, `amount`, `student_name`, `mobile_no`, `father_name`, `clas`, `uid`, `exam_lavel`

last one is transaction success table
i have used to join command

```
public function show_payment_modal()
{
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('student_login');
        $this->db->where('stauts'=='active');
        $this->db->join('student_registration', 'student_login.student_id = 
        student_registration.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('stud_trans_temp', 
        'stud_trans_temp.student_id=student_registration.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('stud_trans', 
        'stud_trans.referenceno=stud_trans_temp.reference_no', 'left');
        $this->db->where('student_login.status', 'active'); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
}
```

in stud_trans i have two payment mode cash and success
i want to cash mode that depends upon attached image exam_level

Comment: Please post your expected output of above query.

Answer (score 0):

Try some changes in your code marked in.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('student_login');
$this->db->where('stauts', 'active');

$this->db->join('student_registration', 'student_login.student_id = 
    student_registration.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('stud_trans_temp', 
    'stud_trans_temp.student_id=student_registration.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('stud_trans', 
    'stud_trans.referenceno=stud_trans_temp.reference_no', 'left');
$this->db->where('student_login.status', 'active'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean up code some

```
//might need to specify what you want since you have a lot of joins ex. student_registration.id as reg_id
$this->db->select('*');
//can make aliases
$this->db->join('student_registration sr', 'sl.student_id = 
sr.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('stud_trans_temp', 
'stud_trans_temp.student_id = sr.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('stud_trans', 
'stud_trans.referenceno=stud_trans_temp.reference_no', 'left');
$this->db->where('stauts', 'active');
$this->db->where('student_login.status', 'active'); 
//can make this one line or chain them all together
return $this->db->get('student_login sl')->result_array();
```